# How to toggle column in ng2 data table/akveo in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I am integrating ng2-data-table by akveo for my project and have hit a hiccup while toggling the column visibility.
I followed the issue https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/issues/95 to set visibility flag for the column and on toggle update the flag but the data doesn't update in the table.
Could you point what i am missing.

HTML

```
 <div class="row table-control">
 <div class="col-md-6">
 <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search           
 for names..">
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-3">

 </div>
 <div class="col-md-3">
 <ss-multiselect-dropdown [options]="myOptions" [texts]="myTexts" 
 [settings]="mySettings" [(ngModel)]="optionsModel 
 (ngModelChange)="toggle($event)">
 </ss-multiselect-dropdown>        
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="row">
 <ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="rows"></ng2-smart-table>
 </div>
```

TS

```
rows: any = [];
optionsModel: any[];
myOptions: IMultiSelectOption[];  
 settings = {
 mode: 'external',
 hideSubHeader: true,
 actions: {
  add: false, edit: false, delete: false, columnTitle: '', position: 'right'
 },
 columns: {
  enquiry_no: { title: 'Enquiry No', filter: false, show: true }, 
  name: { title: 'Name', filter: false, show: true }, 
 };

 constructor(private enquire: FetchenquirycampaignService) {
 this.enquire.getAllEnquiry().subscribe(data => {
  this.rows = data;
 })
 }

  toggle() {
  var item = this.optionsModel.pop();
  console.log(item);
  console.log(this.settings.columns[item].show);
  this.settings.columns[item].show = !this.settings.columns[item].show;
  console.log(this.settings.columns[item].show);
  }
```

I have used angular-2-dropdown-multiselect to retrieve the id of selected cols, moreover have used LocalDataSource to refresh source on toggle() but still no luck.

Live example: https://ronit123321.github.io/procturV2/enquiry/manage

Answer (score 0):

Found that the actual source of the problem was the settings object which cannot be updated.

So had a dummy setting named "settingUpdater" created and added all the attributes to it. Now on toggle function update this dummyObject and assign value to actual setting.

```
toggle() {
var item = this.optionsModel.pop();
this.settingUpdater.columns[item].show = !this.settings.columns[item].show;
this.settings = Object.assign({}, this.settingUpdater);
}
```